# c# reader.read loop does not work

Tags: c#

I am tying to retrieve some data from mysql database and fill some text boxes.problem is that compiler doesn't go inside the while (rdr.Read()) loop.i have checked my query but it's correct.and also the variable passed to the constructor is correct.
Here is my code

```
namespace LoanApp
{
public partial class TablePopUp : Form
{
    string id;

    public TablePopUp(string var)
    {
        id = var;
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            ConnectDB connection = new ConnectDB();
            MySqlConnection con = connection.setUpConnection();

            con.Open();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM debtors WHERE NIC = 'id'";
            MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
            textBox1.Text = var.ToString();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                txtBoxSearch.Text = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = rdr.GetValue(5).ToString();
                textBox3.Text = rdr.GetValue(4).ToString();

            }

        rdr.Close();
        con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }


   }

}
```

[image]

Comment: The compiler doesn't "go into loops". I guess you want to replace `WHERE NIC = 'id'` with the actual `id`, so use sql parameters

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM debtors WHERE NIC = 'id'"` The col `NIC` doesn't have a value `id`

Comment: Did you check the reader with a break point? The query may be right but that does not mean it gets back any values.

Comment: is there a reason you use a keyword for a variable name? `var` is a keyword in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to replace `WHERE NIC = 'id'` with the actual `id`, so use sql parameters

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM debtors WHERE NIC = @id";
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Tim now program works perfectly.also read about sql parameters lot